# Ordering and Formatting Dates on X-Axis in Seaborn Bar Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, pythonanywhere

This seems so simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I am new to Python and Seaborn, and I am doing all this online at PythonAnywhere.

All I am trying to do is create a simple barplot in seaborn, with dates ordered properly (that is, ascending from left to right), on the x-axis.

When I try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

emp = pd.DataFrame([[32, "5/31/2018"], [3, "2/28/2018"], [40, "11/30/2017"], [50, "8/31/2017"], [51, "5/31/2017"]], 
               columns=["jobs", "12monthsEnding"])

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))

sns.barplot(x = "12monthsEnding", y = "uniqueClientExits", data = emp, 
estimator = sum, ci = None)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

I get this:

[Nice looking bar graph but with the dates ordered descending from left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov6BF.png)

And then when I try to convert the objects to datetime:

(note: i'm using pd.to_datetime() below in order to try and recreate what happens when I use parse_dates in pd.read_csv(), which is how I'm actually creating the dataframe.)

```
emp = pd.DataFrame([[32, pd.to_datetime("5/31/2018")], [3, pd.to_datetime("2/28/2018")], [40, pd.to_datetime("11/30/2017")], [50, pd.to_datetime("8/31/2017")], [51, pd.to_datetime("5/31/2017")]], 
               columns=["jobs", "12monthsEnding"])

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))

sns.barplot(x = "12monthsEnding", y = "uniqueClientExits", data = emp, 
estimator = sum, ci = None)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

I get this:

[Bar plot with the dates in the right order, but WRONG format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2FqV.png)

I get the same bar plot, with the dates ordered properly, but in the full, long datetime format, with the time, etc.  But all I want is the day/month/year.

I've scoured stackoverflow for two days now and nothing has worked.  I'm starting to wonder if part of the reason is because I'm working on PythonAnywhere.  But I also can't find any reason why that would be.

This is driving me nuts.  Looking forward to any assistance.  Thanks.

Comment: @Parfait, thanks for the tip.  This is my first time asking a question, and happy to receive tips like that.  Much appreciated.  I hope my edits make my question workable now.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using your second approach, simply sort and reformat the datetime values to `YYYY-MM-DD` and pass values into `set_xticklabels`. Below demonstrates with random, seeded data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# RANDOM DATA
np.random.seed(62918)
emp = pd.DataFrame({'uniqueClientExits': [np.random.randint(15) for _ in range(50)],
                    '12monthsEnding': pd.to_datetime(
                                          np.random.choice(
                                              pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=50), 
                                          50)
                                      )
                   }, columns = ['uniqueClientExits','12monthsEnding'])

# PLOTTING
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))    
fig = sns.barplot(x = "12monthsEnding", y = "uniqueClientExits", data = emp, 
                  estimator = sum, ci = None, ax=ax)

x_dates = emp['12monthsEnding'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').sort_values().unique()
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates, rotation=45, ha='right')
```

[image: Plot Output]

To check graph output, run a `groupby().sum()`:

```
print(emp.groupby('12monthsEnding').sum().head())

#                 uniqueClientExits
# 12monthsEnding                   
# 2018-01-01                     12
# 2018-01-02                      4
# 2018-01-04                     11
# 2018-01-06                     13
# 2018-01-08                     10
# 2018-01-11                     11
# 2018-01-14                      9
# 2018-01-15                      0
# 2018-01-16                      4
# 2018-01-17                      5
# ...
```

Comment: @Parfait, Can you please elaborate why you used: .sort_values().unique() (when I use it on my end, the x-axis is incorrect and without it it works correctly). Thanks

Comment: @adhg - It depends on your data. For this random example, there were multiple values for same dates but an x-axis only shows unique dates.

Comment: You can also use `fig.autofmt_xdate()` instead of explicitly mentioning the rotation angle.

Comment: This now gives an error FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator

Comment: @Tasty213, given this solution is close to three years old, pandas, seaborn, or matplotlib may have adjusted this date formatting functionality in recent versions.

Comment: If anyone faces this, there is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371798/1820837. `barplot` has an order field, where you can provide a sequence of values in the order you want. As for formatting, I suggest doing that in your dataframe before providing it to `bartplot` instead of updating the x-axis because it might create misalignment with the values on the y-axis

Answer (score 2):

As lopheam mentions in the comments, you can go:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

This automatically rotates the dates and also reduces the number to ticks.