# How to plot months (in order) using Seaborn bar plot?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm unable to display my data that corresponds to each month when using Seaborn barplot.  So please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried the code below, which does display the months in Seaborn bar plot on the x-axis.  However there is no data displayed.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

However, I found code via Seaborn Pair Grid, which displays the data (but it's not in order).  I'd like it ordered using either method.

[image]

```
#Seaborn barplot of categorical values
sns.set(style='whitegrid')
Months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
             'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
sns.barplot(x='LastContactMonth', y='CarInsurance', 
                      data=df, order=Months, palette='Set3')
plt.xticks(rotation=-75)
plt.show(); 


#Pair grid of categorical values 
cat_pg = sns.PairGrid(df,
             x_vars=['LastContactMonth'],
             y_vars=['CarInsurance'],
             aspect=.75, size=10)
plt.xticks(rotation=-75)
cat_pg.map(sns.barplot, palette='Set3');
```

Comment: Please provide us with your example data (x, y). In this way, it will be easier to investigate your case properly.

Comment: Do you check your input data frame format it is in wide format or long format? If your data frame is in long format you need to convert your data frame into long format using function `pd.melt`  since you specified your `x` and `y` in seaborn function. otherwise you may check here :[http://alanpryorjr.com/visualizations/seaborn/barplot/barplot/] & [https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html]

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow (so I'm trying to figure all this out). Would you like a screenshot of the data? I provided a picture of how both the bar plot and pair grid are generated.

Comment: You need double check your name of months in the data frame. I think the list `Months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']` you created does not have in the data frame. Maybe thats why the plot is empty. Because what i see from the pairgrid plot, have **all small letter** for the months. Maybe you need to change the letter into small. `Months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun',  'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']`

Comment: @Shalar Please post a sample of your data. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help

Comment: So the issue was with writing the dates beginning with a capital letter.  I was able to generate my bar plot, but the dates are still not in order.  It looks just about identical to the pair grid graph still.  So I guess there is no way to order the months on the x-axis.

Comment: why? it should be in order, unless you are not oderring the list correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the capital letter in Months list & make sure the list is in order that you desire.

```
Months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']
sns.barplot(x='LastContactMonth', y='CarInsurance', data=df_new, order=Months, palette='Set3')
plt.xticks(rotation=-75)
plt.show()
```

[image]